# How to send multiple values for same input field in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to send multiple input values for the same input field in selenium using python. Below is my code for sending only a single value to the input field. I want to test and run for multiple values.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='path')   
driver.get("http://site")    
username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")  
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")   
username.send_keys("username")  
password.send_keys("password")  
#call the submit button
driver.find_element_by_CSS_selector('#form-login .button')click()
```

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: you mean to say performing login check based on different username and password combinations ?

Comment: if you are agree with @NarendraR then you should use clear() for clear the field and you can send it back different value by sendKeys()

Comment: @narendraR yes ,i want to try for multiple username and password combination.I'm New to selenium,can anyone tell me how can i do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dictionary to achieve this. First declare a dictionary with the user name / password combination you want. Then using foreach you can iterate through this & check for multiple combination

```
userpass = {
    "user1":"pass1",
    "user2":"pass2",
    "user3":"pass3"
}

for un in userpass:
    username.send_keys(un)  
    password.send_keys(userpass[un])
    #rest of your actions
```

Comment: Nice approach for having dictionary.